# Why assign an value using index to one embedded list won't work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's a 3*4 matrix represented by embedded list, when I try to assign the `dp[0][0][0] = 1`, it changes all first value of each list element.

I'm using python 3.7, don't know where's the problem.

I want to change the first value of first [0,0,0,0] to 4

```
dp = [[[0,0,0,0]] * 3] *4
dp[0][0][0] =4
print(dp)
```

output like this

```
[[[4, 0, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0, 0]], [[4, 0, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0, 0]], [[4, 0, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0, 0]], [[4, 0, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0, 0]]]
```

Comment: You should use `[[[0, 0, 0] for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(4)]` so that the lists are re-evaluated each time. Multiplying lists in this way will not clone the list, only create 2 references to the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it like this :

```
dp = [[[0,0,0,0] for y in range(3)] for i in range(4)]
dp[0][0][0] =4
print(dp)
```

Output:

```
[[[4, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]]
```

Have a good day !